# How do I write a test class for the below trigger?

Tags: trigger, unit-test, apex

I have just created the below trigger that is deigned to create a new custom object record(Services) when a custom date field (Service_Date__c) on another custom object (Unit)is equal to "This Month".

The new record will copy the data from the "Unit" record.

Can anyone please advise how to write the unit test for the below code so that I can get coverage and upload to production?

I am very new to apex so please feel free to point out any errors in my code.

Thank you

---

```
Trigger copyunitdetail on Unit__c(before insert,after insert, after update)
{
     List<Services__c> sub=new List<Services__c>();
     for(Unit__c u : Trigger.new)
     {
           if(u.Service_Date__c == 'THIS MONTH')
           {
                   Services__c s=new Services__c();
                   s.Name=u.Name;
                   s.Covered_By_Manuf_Warranty__c=u.Covered_By_Manuf_Warranty__c;
                   s.Date_for_Call_About_Servces__c=u.Date_for_Call_About_Services__c;
                   s.Dell_Tag_Number__c=u.Dell_Tag_Number__c;
                   s.Dongle_Number__c=u.Dongle_Number__c;
                   s.Equipment_Type__c=u.Equipment_Type__c;
                   s.ID__c=u.ID__c;
                   s.Installed_Date_First__c=u.Installed_Date__c;
                   s.Item_Onsite__c=u.Item_Onsite__c;
                   s.Machine_Specific_Notes__c=u.Machine_Specific_Notes__c;
                        s.Manufacturers_Warranty_End_Date__c=u.Manufacturers_Warranty_End_Date__c;
                   s.NX_Number__c=u.NX_Number__c;
                   s.Onsite_with_Customer__c=u.On_Site_With_Customer__c;
                   s.Product__c=u.Product__c;
                   s.Purchase_Date__c=u.Purchased_Date__c;
                   s.Serial_Number__c=u.Serial_Number__c;
                   s.Service_Date__c=u.Service_Date__c;
                   s.Service_Date_Month__c=u.Service_Date_Month__c;
                   s.Service_Engineer__c=u.Service_Engineer__c;
                   s.Service_Month__c=u.Service_Month__c;
                   s.Service_Month_Text__c=u.Service_Mnth__c;
                   s.Shipped_to_a_Customer__c=u.Shipped_to_a_Customer__c;
                   s.Time_Remaining_on_Manuf_Warranty__c=u.Time_Remaining_on_Manuf_Warranty__c;
                   s.Vendor__c=u.Vendor__c;
                   s.XD_Number__c=u.XD_Number__c;


                   sub.add(s);
            }
            if(sub.size()>0)
            insert sub;
     }
}
```

---

Comment: This was closed by the community for being too broad. Typically you won't get a good answer if you ask someone to write test coverage for you; instead you should read up on testing, try something, and then post if you get stuck. If you can write the trigger the tests aren't any harder! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your unit test should create a `Unit__c` record and set the `Service_Date__c` to 'THIS MONTH'. You can then query the `Services__c` record to verify that one was created and all the desired fields are set on it.

Have a look [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods), if you are new to unit tests in Apex

FYI: The `insert` in your code should be outside the `for loop`.

Comment: Thank you Bar, Could you provide an example of what code would be? I have only messed with triggers in a sandbox and never needed coverage before so I have no idea what it should be?

Comment: There are a good few examples in https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

Comment: Basically, what @Bar is saying, very nicely, is that no, he will not write code for you.  Not what this forum is about.  Look at the references he provided, try it out, and come back with specific questions.  People would be glad to help then, but no one is just going to write code for you.

Comment: Thanks SFDC Ninja, my trigger is working fine in sandbox however I am only able to get 14% coverage when I validate in production. When i run tests in Sandbox it passes. Here is my test class. 
@isTest
Public Class SampleTest{
      public static testMethod void myTest(){
              Unit__c u= new Unit__c();
              
              u.Equipment_Type__c = 'Laser';
              insert u;
       }
}

Comment: Your logic only fires when `u.Service_Date__c == 'THIS MONTH'` so in your test you need to set `Service_Date__c` ie add this line: `u.Service_Date__c = 'THIS MONTH'